# ASP.NET MVC Check is mobile in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, global-asax

I want to check if the user is on mobile page inside the function Application_Start in Global.asax, in order to create a mobile display mode.

Is there any way I can do that? 
I tired Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice but i got the exception "Request is not available in this context"

Comment: `Application_Start` is triggered when your ASP.NET application is first started. It doesn't get triggered by each request from a user (hence the lack of access to `Request`), so it's not a good choice for handling a user specific/request specific action

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application_BeginRequest` instead also use `HTTP_USER_AGENT` server variable instead of Request.IsMobileDevice  :

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var u = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
       var uri =  Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
          //put DetectMobileBrowsersCode Here, for exmaple if user agents contains apple , android , etc ...

          if (b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(Left(u, 4)))
          {
              Response.Redirect("http://m.yoursite.com");
          } 
    }
```